# Determining how many entries were present on each day for a constantly shifting daily dataset

Tags: excel

I have searched a lot for a solution to this, but have found nothing.  Maybe that's because it's a little hard to describe, or at least, I'm having trouble describing it for a search engine.

I have two columns of dates, the first column is the date a purchase order was received to be inspected, the second is the date that purchase order was accepted or rejected.  What I would like is a graph with dates on the X-axis, and then the number of purchase orders in the queue on that day on the Y-axis.

Some purchase orders are completed that day, so they would still be counted, but they might not get addressed for days or weeks, so they would be counted on all those days until they were addressed.

I've been trying to do this with a formula, but am stumped.  I feel like I might need to use multiple formulas, or go over to VBA, but my VBA is a little limited.

Edit: Here is a sample dataset.

`Date In      Date Out
 9/1/18       9/1/18
 9/1/18       9/1/18
 9/1/18       9/2/18
 9/1/18       9/3/18
 9/2/18       9/2/18
 9/2/18       9/4/18`

So, it would be 4 for 9/1/18, 4 for 9/2/18, 2 for 9/3/18, and 1 for 9/4/18.

I have tried using COUNTIFS, but I don't know how to check between the two columns for the "between" dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is in column `A` and `B`. Put your dates in column `C` (the X axis of your chart), then in column `D` you can write `=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$1000,"<="&C1,$A$1:$A$1000,">="&C1)`. The `COUNTIFS` function will consider that for each row of data, all conditions must be met to be added to the count (a little weird, but definitely useful). See screenshot.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work.  This only counts the number of rows where the value A1 = B1 = C1.  A1 might not equal B1, but A1 = C1, so it still needs to be counted.

Comment: yes, you're right, I followed a doc somewhere, and it was wrong. I corrected it though, that one should work

Comment: I think he had a typo, that works.  I feel like I tried this and it didn't work!  I must have had some issue with it, but this seems to work!